# Passagem de valor por URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá. Sou novo em PHP e tenho uma dúvida.
Preciso que quando meu usuário acessar o link `https://meusite.com/code.php?id=**01**&key=**12345**` o PHP leia os valores 01 e 12345 e consulte dentro do meu SQL na tabela CHAVE, se existe um ID 01 e se tem a KEY 12345 cadastrada nele. Caso tenha, ele me retorno o valor 1 ou se não tiver, me retorno 0

Sei como criar um conexão no SQL, como checar o valor e me retornar 1 ou 0.
Mas não sei como pegar o valor do LINK, e transformar em variável para fazer essa checagem.
Acho que terei que pegar o valor do link, dividir o ID e a KEY dele e então checar ambas, porém, não sei como fazer isso.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.